# Not starting a distinct region server because hbase.cluster.distributed is false

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hbase, hadoop2

I am getting `Not starting a distinct region server because hbase.cluster.distributed is false` in my HBase RegionServer's logs, though I set:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

in my 2 node HBase cluster.

I am pretty sure it is a `/etc/hosts/` problem. Here's my full config:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>hbase-master:60000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-namenode:8020/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hbase-master</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

both in my master and regionserver. My `/etc/hosts/` file in master:

```
# 127.0.0.1     localhost
# 127.0.1.1     hbase-master

192.168.100.150 hbase-master
192.168.100.151 hbase-regionserver1
192.168.100.152 hadoop-namenode

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and in my regionserver:

```
# 127.0.0.1     localhost
# 127.0.1.1     hbase-regionserver1

192.168.100.150 hbase-master
192.168.100.151 hbase-regionserver1
192.168.100.152 hadoop-namenode

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I am using Hbase 1.2.2 and Hadoop 2.6.2. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

## Update

In a very twisted way, adding

```
192.168.100.150 localhost
```

to both my master's `/etc/hosts` and my regionserver's `/etc/hosts/` and removing two properties with ZooKeeper (quorum and port) from hbase-site.xml on both resolves the issue. This is weird, since I am hardwiring my master's IP to `localhost` on both master and regionserver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the following lines also screw HBase configuration:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

so comment them out and everything works fine:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
# ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
# ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
# ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```